# External executable changes directory while doing Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool, os.system

I am new to Python and Multiprocessing.

Summarized issue: I am running a .py executable which contains a Pool.map(function,list_args) the function it calls contain the line os.system() which it executes a .csh file in the same directory as the initial .py executable. This .csh executable creates a new folder and moves the working directory into it. I believe this where my code fails, I believe that the os.system() does not wait for the .csh executable to finish.

(Ubuntu is the OS on my computer).

Here is part of the code:

```
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def phenix(FILES):
        os.system("mkdir temp_"+str(FILES))
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("cp 5k10_only_atoms.pdb.mtz "+str(FILES)+" temp_"+str(FILES)+"/")
        retval = os.getcwd()
        time.sleep(1)
        os.chdir(str(retval)+"/temp_"+str(FILES))
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("./phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb 5k10_only_atoms.pdb.mtz "+str(FILES)+" scale=True fix_xyz=True >> grabado")
        os.chdir(retval)

        #THE USER INPUTS VALUES FOR THE VARIABLES cores AND list_files

if __name__ == '__main__':
                    p = mp.Pool(cores)
                    p.map(phenix,list_files)
```

The command line

> ./phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb 5k10_only_atoms.pdb.mtz .....and so on

Runs some calculations comparing values insides the files 5k10_only_atoms.pdb.mtz and FILES (another file e.g. "file-01"). It is this command line *phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb* that creates another folder (called temp_dir) and moves the working directory into it to do some calculations and write out files.

Again I am pretty sure that this is where something goes wrong because the phenix command never does anything besides creating a folder named temp_dir. It is only when phenix (a .csh executable) tries to change the working directory that os.system() does not wait for any return and my .py executable continues on to the next command.

Is their some way to let my phenix executable finish its job with out os.system() not waiting for it to finish?

NOTE: I am not able to modify this phenix (.csh) executable. Also the phenix command line does work when I run it directly on the terminal.

Comment: First, I don't see a `.csh` anywhere here. Second, were you expecting the `.csh` script to change the Python process's working directory? It can't do that.

Comment: The phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb is my .csh executable (although it does not have the extension).

Comment: The phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb is my .csh executable (although it does not have the extension, I believe it is an .csh). The things is when I run the os.system("phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb...") WITHOUT doing multiprocessing the executable runs and completes its job. But when I run the os.system("phenix.get_cc_mtz_pdb...") WHILE doing multiprocessing it does not do anything.       [link](https://www.phenix-online.org/documentation/reference/get_cc_mtz_pdb.html)

Comment: Did you happen to read [ask] and [mcve]?